# Forever with npm start and environment variable

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I used to start my application using:

```
DEBUG=chakka ENVIRONMENT=production npm start
```

How can i start it using forever so i wouldn't have to do it everytime i want to test the application? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to know what the application's main script file is.  Open up your package.json file and find out what the `start` script is.  If you're using Express it might be `app.js`.  So we'll assume `app.js` for this example, replace with whatever your file is.

To start the application:

```
DEBUG=chakka ENVIRONMENT=production forever start app.js
```

to restart the application after you've made changes:

```
forever restart app.js
```

Comment: i tried this but getting error `ENVIRONMENT=production forever start app.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js`

Comment: Those are just warnings.  You could set those variables if you like.