# nodejs forever : How to run my npm application

Tags: node.js, forever

Right now i am runnign my nodejs application as `npm start`. i want to run it in background. I found `forever` package for this but dont know how can i run a application that i usually run as `npm start`. So how can i run it using `forever` ?

I follow [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773936/forever-with-npm-start-and-environment-variable) but getting this error:

```
ENVIRONMENT=production forever start app.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

apart of this Is there any other better way to run nodejs in background ?

Comment: i don't see an error, just warnings....?

Answer (score 29):

You are doing it right.

The warnings are just reminding you that some essential information is missing, so it assigns the defaults. To be exact, if your script crashes/exits sooner than a second after start, **forever** will exit as well.

---

If you would like to get rid of those warnings:

```
forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.js
```

---

Furthermore, you can open the `package.json` file, find the:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

and change it to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.js",
    "stop":  "forever stop app.js"
  },
```

Now you can use `npm start` and it will invoke `forever` automatically.

Comment: For anyone seeing this who's using express-generator and starts their application using "npm start", replace

"app.js" with

"\`pwd\`/bin/www"

Answer (score 16):

**In 2022**

Use `forever` npm package ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever )

```
forever start -c "npm <command\>" /path/to/app/dir/
```

**EXAMPLE**

`./` means current directory

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

Answer (score -1):

**For Linux**
*Use terminal and enter in superuser mode, and try these code*

```
$ nohup node <location of of js file> &
$ exit
```

*Note: This '&' is must before you press enter*

or for npm command, just goto the location by cd command where your package.json is stored. Then

```
$ nohup npm start &
$ exit
```

*Note: This '&' is must before you press enter*

*To stop it*

```
$ top
```

You can see process id here, then use following code

```
$ kill -9 <PROCESS_ID>
```